# Changing the shrouds, how would I know how far if I need to?

Tags: sailing, boats

I have a lelievlet and want to add a bowsprit/lignite and a mizzen mast. Therefore I need to know how much I need to change the shrouds, anyone can help me by explaining how?

edit:

What data do I need to have in order to calculate the new setting and how do I calculate them? And about the lignite, how can I know what the length should be?

With the mizzen I have another problem, how would I resolve the shrouds there and mizzen's sheet?

[image]

(Image from http://www.euroship.hu/index.php?pageid=65)

Answer (score 6):

So, there are a number of challenges you face. Firstly, what is the reason for wanting a mizzen? It will change the sailing characteristics significantly, as well as require a lot of work.

**tl;dr** - this is a fair old undertaking to do for no obvious reason.

If you do decide to add one, you have 2 real options - a small, unstayed mizzen off the transom, or a a taller stayed mizzen.

The first won't require a lot of work - your existing shrouds should be fine, however you will need to work a way to mount your mizzen without conflicting with the tiller. Not a major deal, but still fiddly.

The second is likely to require at a minimum:

- A shorter main boom
- A shorter gaff
- A redesigned sail
- Redesigned tiller
- Mizzen shrouds: simplest being 1 to the main mast top, 2 alongside the existing main shroud points, and probably 2 to the transom

Then you need to look at the reinforcement you will require at these points.

Once that is complete, be aware that she will try to point a lot higher, as the shape of the hull is not optimised for 2 masts, so you are likely to use the tiller more, causing a fair amount of drag. Solutions to this can include moving the centreboard or adding extra keels.

Comment: The reason why? Two reasons, Second: Don't you think it would look marvellous? First, I'd like to have some work on board, it will bring me much more pleasure sailing. Also I think it will speed up the boat (but not a necessity). A second thing I want to do (in another question) is to remove the sword (figure above nr 48) and add two at the sides. Great, maybe you're right and I have to design en build my own boat as I won't be done after the swords. I also want... ... ... ;) Am in the decision making phase.

Comment: Shorten the boom and so the gaff shouldn't be needed. Just let the mizzen boom stick out at the stern.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes. hope you like 'glass. a mizzen really is not as useful as a forward spar. a bow sprint would allow you to make a schooner out of that boat and would be a better performer. had both. mizzories make great work bench legs and yard sculpture. a forespar makes for a faster boat. also try never-wet as a bottom paint and she will go 30% fast .. I promise. my cal 28 was limited to 4.5 kts, now with both I am at a scary 8.3